# Solving for a convolved function inside an integral

Tags: convolution, image-processing

I have an imaging system that produces a signal in a pixel, in part, by responding to incident radiance $L(\lambda)$ that passes through a filter with transmission $T(\lambda)$. Lumping all the other parameters under a generic constant I can write the signal:
$S = k\cdot\int L(\lambda)\ast T(\lambda)d\lambda\,$.
I'm trying to find a way to determine, or even estimate $L(\lambda)$. The system is such that I know $S, k$, and $T(\lambda)$. Is there a way to recover the incident radiance? Note, I am not necessarily looking for a closed form solution, approximation is fine.

Comment: Are S and L functions of time?  Your $\ast$ isn't making sense and you didn't name the source equation.

Comment: S and L are not functions of time. L, the radiance, is a function of wavelength. It's convolved with the transmission T of a color filter and summed over all wavelengths to produce the signal S (pixel value), expressed in DN in the final digital image. Not sure what you mean by source equation.

Comment: This might help:  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/65977/fourier-transform-of-sampled-reflectance-measurements

Comment: So $L(\lambda) * T(\lambda) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty L(\lambda - l) T(\lambda) dl$?

Comment: No, perhaps I'm using convolution incorrectly here. The functions are multiplied together. For instance, at 500nm let's say the radiance is 5 $(W/m^2Sr)$, and the filter transmission at that wavelength is 0.5, so the signal recorded is $2.5\cdot k$