Remove noise from detector signal to allow accurate area calculation of a section of the curve
I am a final year PhD student with no background in signal processing, I would like some help to minimise the noise from a signal.
Data was recorded from a flame ionisation detector, attached to a gas chromatograph. This data is in the form of a signal response (mV) at a given time (min), and was sampled at $12.5 \, \textrm{Hz}$.
The aim is to remove as much noise from the signal as possible, such that the presence of a secondary peak can be determined and the area quantified. This peak would appear as a "bump" along the original line.
An attempt at smoothing has been made by calculating a weighted median for each data point using
$$ x \left( t \right) = 0.25  y \left( t - 1 \right) + 0.5 y \left( t \right) + 0.25 y \left( t + 1 \right) \tag{1} \label{1} $$
Where $x \left( t \right)$ is the smoothed data point, $y$ is the original data point, and $t$ denotes the time at which each data point was recorded with $t - 1$ and $t + 1$ referring to the previous and subsequent data points, respectively. This method did not provide adequate smoothing, it is expected that repeated uses would lead to an unacceptable amount of loss of the original signal, rendering the process pointless.
The graph below is an example of the signal I would like to smooth. The expected peak can be seen between approximately $14.2$ and $14.35$ min. I am aware it's tiny, however I am certain it is not noise itself as the location is exactly as predicted from previous experiments.

While I do not expect anyone to do my work for me, I have little experience with MatLab and no experience with Python. Therefore, a script, or directions towards one would be greatly appreciated.
Regarding the calculation of the peak area, I do not believe I require assistance.

You can start with a generalization of your formula (1) using more data points (5, 7, instead of your 3 pts) and different sets of weighting coefficients (triangle, binomial etc.), rather than repeatedly applying the 3-point weighted moving average. But a more reliable approach is to learn about signal processing techniques developed specifically for your subfield, like application notes of GC instrument manufacturers (https://www.agilent.com/cs/library/support/documents/a16024.pdf, https://www.agilent.com/en/product/gas-chromatography/gc-detectors/flame-ionization-detector and the like).

When examining a wide body of related literature, you can even find out that your problem is solved by using a dedicated measurement technique or switching to a different flavor of FID instrument rather than with an ingenious smoothing algorithm. If you fail to find any useful solution, my congratulations: you are on the track to develop a more sensitive GC method. If so, it gives you a strong motivation to research into the statistics of your measurement data, this research would potentially result in an acclaimed publication or even more significant achievement.

In search of dedicated SP techniques for GC measurements you can ask your question in the chemistry.SE. See what chemistry experts recommend as regards SP techniques for scientific measurement processing: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60022/what-measurement-errors-occur-in-an-inteferogram/60031#comment120160_60031 .

I can provide a clear direction, but it is going to be a lot of work given the confession of no background in signal processing, MATLAB or Python. If you are prepared to roll up your sleaves, this will be the clear and rewarding path toward the optimum solution applicable to future opportunities in data collection and signal estimation.
Quick Answer if there are bigger fish to fry:
The deeper details are below, but if time and interest is limited (or opportunity to dig into this) then the minimum path toward a smoother curve is to use the filtfilt zero phase filtering function that is available in MATLAB, Octave and Python. This will provide a smoothed result without shifting the horizontal axis due to filter delay. Without further information of the signal statistics (as detailed below), start with a simple moving average over n samples using the python function below (Matlab would be similar). Just adjust nsamps and evaluate the result trading smoothing with losing resolution of the waveform shape.
import scipy.signal as sig
import numpy as np
nsamps = 20      # number of samples to do moving average
output = sig.filtfilt(np.ones(nsamps), nsamps, waveform)

'filtfilt' actually does a moving average filter twice which is not optimum for white noise (but perhaps close enough, and IF the noise was even white). If you are ok with compensating for the filter delay be removing the initial $(N-1)/2$ samples the following is the optimum solution in Python assuming the noise process is white:
import scipy.signal as sig
import numpy as np
nsamps = 20      # number of samples to do moving average
delay = int((nsamps-1)/2)
output = sig.lfilter(np.ones(nsamps), nsamps, waveform)[delay:]

Deeper details if time and ability to recapture the data properly:
Evaluating the signal statistics both in the time and frequency domain will be very helpful, if not essential. Ultimately we want to understand how stationary the signal is as this will indicate how effective further averaging will be (and if the data can be collected again, how long to dwell at any given condition to optimize the estimate). A great tool for doing this is the Allen Deviation, and I have provided several other posts here that go into much more detail on using it for this purpose. I will link those details below but the tool to get to help with evaluating the Allen Deviation is either Stable32 or the Python package "allantools".  With that you can quickly assess how long we can assume the data to be sufficiently stationary such that further averaging will actually benefit in reducing the standard deviation of the estimate (minimizing the noise) with a simple uniform average. For example, if the noise process is white (uniform power spectral density in the frequency domain), a uniform average is the optimum solution. The ADEV curve will go down at $1/\sqrt{\tau}$ in this case for the duration of time in which this approximation is valid.
As an example of this I included the plot below from Wikipedia showing the $1/\sqrt{\tau}$ out to $\tau=3$ seconds for this particular example data that was used to create that plot (the units don't matter, but ADEV is typically used to assess frequency stability for clocks or position stability for gyroscopes; just tell the tool you use that your units are frequency and the result will have this significance). This result shown means we could capture the data for as long as 3 seconds (at the one condition) and the noise would be minimized by a uniform average over that duration.  Further we hit a floor in the result out to 7 seconds, which means further averaging would continue to reduce the overall noise, but not with the same reduction. Further an importantly, if we were to average an interval past 7 seconds, the result would actually begin to degrade (due to the signal not being stationary enough over that longer time interval-- which will ultimately occur to any signal we measure).
For capturing many signals as the OP is doing, it is the duration at which the ADEV starts to turn up, or more specifically turns up and goes past the time interval we decide to average for any one sample (one sample being one point on the OP's final curve showing the noise reduced result), that dictates how quickly all of the samples need to be computed (basically we want to ensure that the experiment hasn't drifted beneath us in being able to compare a later measurement group on the right side of the plot to an earlier measurement group on the left side of the plot.

This process assumes the data can be recaptured for minimum noise as from that measurement such necessary statistics can be extracted. This necessitates holding the experiment at a static condition and taking a long run at that state to determine the stationarity (using ADEV).
The ADEV provides the time domain assessment of signal stability and how long we have to make measurements. Spectrum plots (both FFT's and the Welch Power Spectral Density) provide excellent assessment in the frequency domain characteristics, and specifically if the resulting signal is "white" or not as determined with ADEV, and if there are portions of the frequency that can be removed with optimized filtering based on the spectral shape of the noise.
Below are posts where I provide more details in the effective use of both of these tools. There are many more considerations such as the sampling rate, confirmation of effective anti-alias filtering ahead of the sampler, and the noise floor of the measurement itself, but starting with a solid assessment of the time and frequency characteristics as described here can go a long way toward achieving optimum estimates from signal captures.
ADEV for time domain evaluation:
How to interpret Allan Deviation plot for gyroscope?
How to interpret ADEV plot?
Bias instability in Gyroscopes : AVER / ADEV
1/f noise: Why does the Allan Deviation remain constant, while standard error of mean keeps decreasing for long averages?
FFT and Welch Spectrum for frequency domain evaluation:
Larger FFT vs multiple averaged FFTs for detecting small CW signals
You'll notice a lot of my answers are based on using Python for signal processing. I love that tool and if you have little experience in MATLAB or Python but want to jump in and make it a practical option, I have an online course starting THIS WEEK titled "Python Applications for Digital Design and Signal Processing". This is the FAST PATH to getting going with Python for practical use such as the application described here. There is still an opportunity to sign up: more info and registration is at this link: Boston IEEE. This course and me as instructor will be accessible through Dec 1st!

Python Applications for Digital Design and Signal Processing: I believe, courses like this are in great demand in industry and academia. Good intro presentation here, by the way.    Congrats!

Thank you very much, Mr Boschen, your response is both very helpful and thorough. I have a small query regarding the lfilter function. The curve I have presented here is a trimmed version of the full data set, which was collected over 40 minutes. If this function requires removing the first (N-1)/2 samples, would it be viable to use the collected data from say 13-15 min? So that the irrelevant data (13-14 min) is removed, and the remainder is smoothed effectively. Your course sounds extremely useful, however this is my last bit of data collection before fully committing to thesis writing!

N is the length of the filter which won’t be anywhere near the length of your data set. The relevance of the data over 40 minutes would be revealed by repeating the data collection while not changing anything at all (effectively one sample on your horizontal axis) for 40 minutes and evaluating the ADEV of that result—- as I pointed out that would tell you how much you can really discern when comparing the data collected now to data collected 40 minutes from now as you change parameters. You could likely have other drift contributions that have nothing to do with your independent variable
